# Grouping records within a view in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, group-by, records

I have the following code in my Rails 3 application:

**Show view (from another model called animal.rb)**

```
 <% @animal.labs.each do |lab| %>
    <li>
      <%= lab.TestDone.strftime("%d %b. %Y") %> 
      <h5><%= lab.TestType %></h5>
      <h6><%= lab.TestLower %></h6> 
      <b><%= lab.TestResult %></b> 
      <h6><%= lab.TestUpper %></h6>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

**lab model**

```
belongs_to :animal
default_scope :order => "TestDone DESC", :group => "TestDone"
```

The above code successfully group all results by date. However, it only shows the first of each value after the date.

For example, if the output was originally (before the grouping) like this:

```
<li>
 26 April 2012
 <h5>Glucose</h5>
 <h6>1.0</h6>
 <b>1.8</b>
 <h6>2.0</h6>
</li>

<li>
 26 April 2012
 <h5>WBC</h5>
 <h6>1.1</h6>
 <b>2.8</b>
 <h6>3.0</h6>
</li>

<li>
 26 April 2012
 <h5>ABC</h5>
 <h6>1.0</h6>
 <b>1.6</b>
 <h6>2.0</h6>
</li>
```

then it would output the following after the grouping:

```
<li>
 26 April 2012
 <h5>Glucose</h5>
 <h6>1.0</h6>
 <b>1.8</b>
 <h6>2.0</h6>
</li>
```

What is the correct way of producing something like this:

```
<li>26 April 2012</li>
<li>
  <h5>Glucose</h5>
  <h6>1.0</h6>
  <b>1.8</b>
  <h6>2.0</h6>
</li>
<li>
 <h5>WBC</h5>
 <h6>1.1</h6>
 <b>2.8</b>
 <h6>3.0</h6>
</li>
<li>
 <h5>ABC</h5>
 <h6>1.0</h6>
 <b>1.6</b>
 <h6>2.0</h6>
</li>
```

So I have a date heading and then every record with that date is listed below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way would be to use `group_by` like so:

```
 <% @animal.labs.group_by{|l| l.TestDone.strftime("%d %b. %Y") }.each do |testdate,labs| %>
   <li><%= testdate %></li>
   <% labs.each do |lab| %>
     <li>
       <h5><%= lab.TestType %></h5>
       <h6><%= lab.TestLower %></h6> 
       <b><%= lab.TestResult %></b> 
       <h6><%= lab.TestUpper %></h6>
     </li>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: That looks way more elegant than anything I've tried so far. One thing though, the testate is actually called TestDone. I've tried everything to get it to work but it won't load the value. Any hints?

Comment: @dannymcc Group_by will only group things that are exactly the same, your TestDone probably includes different hours, minutes and seconds for each lab. I've edited my answer to use the full block syntax of group_by to pre-process TestDone before the grouping operation.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping not works the way you want to use it. First, yo ushould not group it in your default_scope, but you may use some aggreagation in the view, or in the controller.

Model:

```
default_scope :order => "TestDone DESC"
```

View:

```
<% prev = nil %>
<% @animal.labs.each do |lab| %>
    <%= "</ul></li>" if prev != nil && prev != lab.TestDone %>
    <%= "<li>"+lab.TestDone.strftime("%d %b. %Y")+"<ul>" if prev != lab.TestDone %>
      <li>
        <h5><%= lab.TestType %></h5>
        <h6><%= lab.TestLower %></h6> 
        <b><%= lab.TestResult %></b> 
        <h6><%= lab.TestUpper %></h6>
      </li>
    <% prev = lab.TestDone %>
<% end %>
<%= "</ul></li>" if prev != nil %>
```

Not the most pretty solution, but it is based on your code.
Basically you need to store the last element's date, in order to compare it with the actual element's date. If they differ, then the new date must be shown. Because they ordered by date, the elements with the same date are close to each other.

I think that is what you was looking for.